# How to use a base class template member function in derived?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, std-function, stdbind

how to use a base class template function in a derived case?

Example:

```
Class A{

    protected:
       template<typename... Args>
            std::vector<torch::Tensor> generate_value(const size_t& generated_points, std::function<int(const Args&...)> function, const Args&... args);
};
```

```
class B : protected A{
   public:
      B() : A(){}
   protected:
     std::vector<torch::Tensor> generate_values(const size_t& generated_points, const size_t& column){
        return this->generate_values(generated_points, std::bind(&A::inner_generation, this, std::placeholders::_1), column);
     }

     <torch::Tensor inner_generation(const size_t& column);
};
```

Compiling use Clang I get the following error:

```
 error: no matching member function for call to 'generate_values'
        return this->generate_values(generated_points, function, column);
               ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'std::function<torch::Tensor (const Args &...)>
            std::vector<torch::Tensor> generate_values(const size_t& generated_points, std::function<torch::Tensor(const Args&...)> function, const Args&... args)
```

I am not sure what is the issue.

I hope someone could guide me.

Originally, I had the function with same name, it was only finding the one in `class B`. I have then changed the names it is still not found. I am not sure is that due to the  `template`.

Comment: `<torch::Tensor` ? what is this?

Comment: please post a [mcve]

Comment: It is a desing issue : Don't mix static an dynamic polymorphism. Pick either one since you can't do a virtual template in the baseclass. So either your base class has a full template implementation usable in the derived class OR you need a virtual method (that isn't templated)

Comment: @PepjinKramer there is no virtual method / dynamic polymorphism in the code.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number  `torch::Tensor` is at type from [link](https://pytorch.org/)

Comment: `<torch::Tensor inner_generation(const size_t& column);` is a syntax error. And a [mcve] does not require `std::vector`, `std::function` or `torch::Tensor`. If you use stuff you should not remove the includes from the code. The code you posted will cause a lot of compiler errors

Comment: `Class A` is also not correct

Comment: moreover the method is called `A::generate_value`, the method you try to call is `generate_values`. There are too many typos in this code.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number sorry for the confusion. I am new to the platform, and I needed guidance. Thank you for sharing the link so, can improve from that aspect.

Comment: `std::function` is a pretty expensive beast – if you have a template anyway, why don't you just accept as another template parameter? `template <typename F, typename ... A> std::vector<...> gen(/*...*/ F&& f, A&& ... a) { /*...*/ f(std::forward<A>(a)...; /*...*/ }` – you could easily pass lambdas to then, though `std::bind` would still be fine.

Comment: frankly, its not specific to SO, that the code you posted does not reproduce the error. If you need help with some code you need to show that code, not other code that has other errors

Comment: you can [edit] the question to show your actual code

Comment: [Demonstrating](https://godbolt.org/z/enzhMMa9r) my proposition…

Comment: Actually, with a generic template parameter you can have that even simpler, *only*
 accept the functor and let the lambda care for the additional parameters: `template <typename F> int A::demo(int n, F&& f) { return n + f(); } int B::demo(int n, int x, int y, int z) { return A::demo(n, [this, x, y, z]() { return myDemo(x, y, z); });` or a bit simpler with default capture `[=]() { /*...*/ }`

Comment: (Lambda and) return type of `std::bind` are not `std::function`, so doesn't match your template.

Comment: @Jarod42 I also that of that, I tried a lambda function I get the same error.

Comment: @Aconcagua Thank you for this comment. I really didn't know if I should use `std::function` or just a template. I will give it a try. Much appropriate it.

Comment: @Aconcagua Your solution is exactly what i need. Would consider adding as an answer so I can vote it up. I am sure it might help other people that might be considering doing something similar. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::function` is rather expensive in usage and little flexible – if you go along with yet another template parameter you are more efficient, more flexible and even get simpler code:

```
class A
{
protected:
    template<typename F, typename... Args>
    std::vector<torch::Tensor> generate_value
    (
        size_t generated_points, // no benefit from reference...
        F&& f // the function/functor to execute
        Args&&... args // allows perfect forwarding
    )
    {
        f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    } 
};

std::vector<torch::Tensor> B::generate_values(size_t generated_points, size_t column)
{
    return generate_values
    (
        generated_points,
        // simply use a lambda, it's just more convenient:
        [this](size_t column) { return inner_generation(column); },
        // though the result of `bind` would be just as valid...
        column // and the parameter...
    );
}
```

Though if using lambdas (or `std::bind` as well, if you bind the values directly instead of using place holders) you don't even need additional parameters:

```
template<typename F>
std::vector<torch::Tensor> A::generate_value(size_t generated_points, F&& f)
{
    f();
}

std::vector<torch::Tensor> B::generate_values(size_t generated_points, size_t column)
{
    return generate_values
    (
        generated_points,
        [this, column] { return inner_generation(column); }
        // alternatively with default bindings:
        //[=] { return inner_generation(column); }
    );
}
```

Which one to choose? Well, a matter of personal taste mainly – unless you want to do the same multiple times with different variables, then the former variant is of advantage for not having to create multiple lambdas:

```
std::vector<torch::Tensor> B::generate_values
(
    size_t generated_points,
    size_t column1,
    size_t column2 // now one more...
)
{
    auto gen = [this](size_t column) { return inner_generation(column); };
    auto v1 = generate_values(generated_points, gen, column1);
    auto v2 = generate_values(generated_points, gen, column2);
    // union both, create difference or do whatever is appropriate...
    return ...;
}
```

This latter example might not be meaningful in your concrete case, but might come into play in other scenarios ;)

Side note: Just for explanation: The original variant fails for neither the result of `bind` nor a lambda actually being a `std::function` object, thus not matching your template parameter. You can solve by creating the `std::function` object explicitly:

```
return A::generate_values
(
    generated_points,
    std::function([this](size_t const& column) { return inner_generation(column); }),
    // alternatively with `bind`ing, though the place holder makes
    // explicitly specifying the template argument necessary:
    //std::function<torch::Tensor(size_t const&)>
    //(
    //    std::bind(&B::inner_generation, this, std::placeholders::_1)
    //),
    column
);
```

Note, too, that in the original code of the question the return types of the `std::function` instantiations do not match either (first `int`, then `torch::Tensor` – unless `torch::Tensor` happens to be a `typedef` for `int`…).